# Is there a resource about integer constructions and motivations?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

I have an assignment about the foundations of mathematics.

I am trying to compile a list where I get common construction of integers and a small writing about the constructor and their explanation.

For example, I have the ordered pair construction by Dedekind, and his explanation via his principle of “generality”, where he writes that definitions appearing in a restricted form can be extended to avoid arbitrariness.

What about the original constructors of other constructions, where can I read about their commentaries?

Comment: E.Bloch, [The Real Numbers and Real Analysis](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Real_Numbers_and_Real_Analysis/r0qcU9U2_I4C) and F.Waismann, [Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Thinking/JWLDAgAAQBAJ)

Comment: The ordered pair construction is for rational numbers, not integers.

Comment: There is also an ordered pair construction of integers from natural numbers

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in “introduction to mathematical thinking” I was reading the chapter on construction of integers and the author mentions a hueristic principle “principle of permanence of forms” and says mathematicians want to preserve existing structure as much as possible. Is this still true? How do I know I’m not reading stuff that is outdated printed in 1952

Comment: @Conifold ... Sometimes we construct $\mathbb Z$ by taking ordered pairs in $\mathbb N$ with equivalence relation $(x,y) \sim (u,v) \Longleftrightarrow x+v = u+y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a good resource: it is the book called Numbers,
by 8 authors (Springer, 1991). The first chapter of this book written by K. Mainzer is dedicated to the history of constructions of integers and rational numbers.

Comment: Great I’ll check it out thanks so much